# Iphone How to change InterFace?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

i'm making app that the main page include TableView but i want when i click in any cell in the tableView open a webView, how can i make it ...
this is my code any way to do what i want

can i change the interface file or create a web view from the code or ...

---

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize tblMain, rows, timer;

NSURL *url;
NSString *jsonreturn;
NSData *jsonData;
NSError *error;
NSDictionary *dict;
UITableViewCell *cell;
static NSString *CellIdentifier;

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self GetData];
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0 target:self selector:@selector(GetData) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
}

-(void)GetData{
    url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"file://localhost/Users/mac/Documents/json.json"];
    jsonreturn = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url];
    NSLog(jsonreturn);
    jsonData = [jsonreturn dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF32BigEndianStringEncoding];
    dict = [[[CJSONDeserializer deserializer] deserializeAsDictionary:jsonData error:&error] retain];
    rows = [dict objectForKey:@"savola"];
    NSLog(@"Array: %@",rows);
    [self.tblMain reloadData];

}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [rows count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }

    dict = [rows objectAtIndex: indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ - %@", [dict objectForKey:@"company"], [dict objectForKey:@"price"]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [dict objectForKey:@"time"];

    return cell;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // open a web view
}


@end
```

Comment: Am a beginner in iphone i dont know any thing about this

Comment: We are a very visual community, could you provide the code that you have tried?

Comment: If you are beginner,try to google it,and then if you get stucked ,return here ..

Comment: the problem in google it show to you many ways i want the easiest one

Comment: why you all hate my question i only need help?

Comment: divide your problem in pieces to search on google ...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Before u post your question here ,do some minimum research, though if u dont get,come n post here ,

Create a new project--> add a file which is subclass of `UITableView` , now inside `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method navigate it to a new class and do your stuffs in the new class (like loading web view, add a web view in xib)

Comment: Sorry agin but i have create the new class and i have ready it but how can i call it the codes i found in google havent work with me

Comment: @user183790  yourNewclass * obj = [yourNewclass alloc]init];
       [self presentModalViewController:obj animated:YES];   this code ill navigate u to the new class

Answer (score -1):

Create one viewController say MyWebviewcontroller along with xib(check with xib for user interface while creating viewcontroller).

Open MyWebViewControlller.xib and add webview.

then in didSelectRowAtIndexPath write code:

```
MyWebviewcontroller *viewController =  [[MyWebviewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName:@"MyWebviewcontroller" bundle:nil];
[self.view addSubView:viewController.view];
```